# Making "heatmap" based on point value not point density using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, interpolation

I have a CSV file containing readings of dissolved oxygen at various points along an estuary.
I would like to make a layer displaying these results, where the colour (e.g., dark blue for high O2 light blue for low O2) is a gradient between all of the points.

The effect I imagine is similar to a heatmap, but based solely on the point value, and should gradate between points based on they're respective values.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As you asking "how to categorize a point layer based on numerical values"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "spatial interpolation" problem, and can be done with a number of methods, for example inverse distance weighting for a quick and ad-hoc method, or kriging for a formal, statistical model-based method.

Your GIS license may or may not let you compute these things, but "spatial interpolation" is the thing you need to search for. You should also research spatial interpolation in the statistics literature for more.